# How do I "shift" axis values in Seaborn (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I'm relatively new to Seaborn and I'm trying to plot the distribution of WhatsApp messages by time but I don't quite get it yet.

I've got the WhatsApp chat in a df sorted by date, time, sender and message. If I plot `displot(df["Times"], bins=24)`, I get a histogram that makes sense. Now, obviously, the histogram goes from 00:00 to 23:59.

How can I "shift" the histogram, so it goes from like 04:00 to 03:59 which would make more sense here?

Also, how can I change the values on the x-Axis? Due to the Datetime format the values all have today's date in front of them which looks stupid in the histogram. I want it to say `2 pm` instead of `10-18-2020 14:00:00`.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the X axis range in seaborn in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54822884/how-to-change-the-x-axis-range-in-seaborn-in-python)

Comment: This approach shows how to create a histogram per hour and set custom ticklabels: [Histogram per hour - matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244590/histogram-per-hour-matplotlib)